# rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

As the title says, I'm getting this error

```
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23)
```

Every time i do archive, i tried all solutions out there like updating cocoapods and the work around

```
source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

But still getting the same error, i even uninstalled project's pods and did fresh installation and still no luck

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.